# Google Calendar Delegates?

Tags: google-calendar

I've decided to start using my Google Calendar through iCal on my Mac. Although I've got a question regarding an annoying issue I'm having.

When I go about adding calendars to my Google Calendar and sync it via iCal, it puts the main calendar where it's supposed to, then it puts the rest of my calendars under a heading called 'Delegates'. I don't know what it means, but is there a way to stop Google from doing this? I just want all my calendars to appear under one heading, the Google one (like the incoming payments calendar in the image below)

I'm not sharing any calendars with any friends or family and I still just can't work this out :( Please help me find out where I'm going wrong :(

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/18660955/screenshots/Screen%20Shot%202012-08-01%20at%2017.14.50.png

Comment: This might be a Mac-specific issue. As such, you might get better answers at [apple.se].

Comment: Ok, I've now done that. Thank you very much :)

Comment: New question is here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58927/google-calendar-delegates

Answer (score 0):

Answers from [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/16018) (courtesy [@pohsyb](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/7207/pohsyb)) :

> Short Answer: You cannot easily clean that up.
>
> Long Answer: When you have delegate calendars, that typically means
>   that you are given permission to view (maybe edit) someone else's
>   calendar. This is why there is special interface to deal with
>   delegation and they are grouped in their own section of the calendar
>   list.
>
> Behind the scenes, google treats each calendar you create as its own
>   principal (almost like its own account), so iCal treats all the non
>   default calendars as delegates. To confuse things further, you can
>   actually can share google calendars so iCal could never tell the
>   difference between an actual shared calendar and new calendar you
>   added.
>
> The only solution is to move all your events into the default calendar
>   or move your calendars to a service which handles multiple calendars
>   in a better way (Yahoo, Exchange, iCalServer)

[and](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/83307) (courtesy of [@Jan Fabry](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/654/jan-fabry)):

> Since late 2012, you can add additional calendars to your main CalDAV account by going to https://www.google.com/calendar/syncselect. After you have done this, you can uncheck the delegate calendars in the iCal settings.